# How to configure webpack to look for index.js when importing a folder?

Tags: webpack

As of right now Webpack will only automatically load index.js from a folder if the folder name's first letter is capitalized. I am using es2015 and react presets. thanks.

edit: if i restart webpack, then it will work. I don't know why.

Comment: It should work for all kinds of folders. Can you upload your code to a repo and share the link?

Comment: well I switched presets from es2015 to env and it works now. Can anyone please explain? From my understanding, env will try to configure Webpack to whatever your code needs, so is that why it fixed it?

Comment: nope. Switch back to es2015 and see if it breaks again.